# 3 trigonometric equations in 3 unknowns (two scalars and an angle)

Tags: trigonometry

$$\begin{align}
T \sin\theta &= R \sin 15^\circ  \\
600 + T \cos\theta &= R \cos 15^\circ \\ 
10800 \cos\theta &= 7 T      
\end{align}$$

Show that $\theta = 21.2^\circ$, $T = 1438$, and $R = 2009$.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and state where you are stuck.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You can format maths with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

from the first two equations we get
$$\frac{T\sin(\theta)}{600+T\cos(\theta)}=\tan(15^{\circ})$$
from the last equation we have $$T=\frac{10800}{7}\cos(\theta)$$ plugging this in the equation above we get
$$\frac{\frac{10800}{7}\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}{600+\frac{10800}{7}\cos(\theta)^2}=\tan(15^{\circ})$$
you must solve this equation for $\theta$